# MATLAB How to turn matrix into a graphical grid with numbers in it?

Tags: matlab

I'm working on a project and am trying to be able to generate a very specific type of graphical output in MATLAB and am not sure how to do it:

First, I want to be able to take, say, a 3x3 matrix, and generate an image that's basically a 3x3 grid with the numbers which are the matrix entries in the appropriate spaces on the grid.

I also want to be able to assign arbitrary colours to different grid squares if possible.

Does anyone know a simple way to go about this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
a = reshape(1:9, 3,3)
imagesc(a)
grid on
text(1,1,'1', 'fontsize', 18)
set(gca, 'xtick', [0.5,1.5,3.5])
set(gca, 'ytick', [0.5,1.5,3.5])
grid off
```

try it. maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the IMAGE or IMAGESC function. It takes a matrix as input and displays a grid, whereas each segment (or "pixel") corresponds to the respective matrix element.

E.g. try

```
 imagesc( randn(3,3) )
```

IMAGESC scales the input values to 0 and 1 before displying (In contrast to IMAGE, which takes the values directly).

The mapping of numbers to colors is adjusted by the specific colormap (see COLORMAP function) of the axis.

Comment: thanks that's helpful. but is there a way to have it display the numbers themselves in the grid, and can I change the colours of the grid squares arbitrarily (i.e. NOT have the colours be representative of the associated numbers)?

Comment: You can use the text function as in argans post to display the numbers on top of the (with arbitrarily choosen colors) image output.